# Jasmine erro - Uncaught [object Object] thrown

Tags: testes-de-unidade, jasmine, angular

Quando executo o meu teste recebo o seguinte erro `Uncaught [object Object] thrown` cada vez que o teste é executado ele fala que o erro é em local diferente, não consigo entender o motivo. Algumas vezes o teste passa sem acontecer esse erro porem são poucas vezes o maior problema é que a descrição desse erro não é muito descritiva.Segue uma foto de exemplo:

### Edição

Sempre que executo os testes obtenho o mesmo erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém cada vez em um lugar diferente e em um teste diferente, por exemplo este teste da foto passou no teste anterior, porem ao executar o teste novamente o erro apareceu nele (como na foto).
O codigo dele é o seguinte:

```
   it('Given_invalidCnpj_When_RegisterOrg_Then_ExpectFalsy', () => {
    expect(service.validateCNPJ("19737128000161")).toBeFalsy();
});
```

como podemos ver não a nada demais para gerar um erro, isso esta tornando a identificação deste erro absurdamente difícil pra mim. Lembrando que se eu executar o teste novamente não vai dar erro neste teste, ele vai passar e o erro ira aparecer em outro teste em outro componente, sem relação nenhuma com o da imagem.

Comment: Possui código? Mais detalhes? Precisamos de evidências para poder ajudar.

Comment: Desculpa @Jackson é que como cada hora acontece em um componente diferente então não sei exatamente o que mostrar :/

Comment: Tudo bem, vamos por parte, "Dividir para conquistar", vamos ao primeiro erro, poste o que está acontecendo e posteriormente iremos ajustando o restante.

Comment: Vamos la, vou editar e adicionar algumas informações. como por exemplo o código do teste que der erro nesta execução

Comment: Encontrei o problema, obrigado pela atenção Jakson!

Comment: Que isso, que bom que conseguiste :D

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei onde estava o problema, um companheiro de equipe adicionou estas duas linhas para testar e acabou não retirando, não sei por qual motivo ela gerava este erro bem genérico.
A solução foi apenas retira-las

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]